# How to filter a list of object by multiple fields in Java?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, filter

I would like to filter a list of object by multiple fields but these fields, which used for filtering can change. For example;

Assume that we have an Employee class with some properties:

```java
@Data
public class Employee {
   private Integer id;
   private Integer age;
   private String gender;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

}
```

What is the best way to code a method that filter by sometimes age and gender or sometimes only firstName? (Samples can be reproduced, i.e. for this example it has 5 properties, so there are 5! = 120 possibilities)
Could it be coded using lambda or something else in Java?

P.S. : Any possibilities are not predefined. Whatever comes from the request it should filter by it. I believe the example below will make this issue clear:

Assume that we have a Filter object with the same properties as Employee's. If age is given and the others are null, this service will filter only by age. Or only gender and firstName are given, it should get employees by the criteria.

Comment: Create `Set<Predicate<Employee>>` and choose a random predicate every time you process the stream.

Comment: What are the possible combinations? Are they predefined or chosen in some random order?

Comment: Possible combinations are not predefined, it could be one of n! . Actually, I'll use this as a service. So whatever comes from the request, it should filter by it.

Comment: What comes from the request?

Comment: @okduman open to defining an `enum` which maps these five attributes (type) to a `Predicate<Employee>` which is specific to the filtering? Or would the condition to filter also be a part of your Request? In which case, it would be interesting to know, how have you designed your Request object to be?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `filter` function. The way this function works is that, if your expression evaluates to true, it will return it to the resulting stream.

A sample snippet would be:

```java
//Assuming employeeList is an ArrayList of Employee:
employeeList.stream().filter((e) -> e.age>25 && "M".equals(e.gender)); //Gives you a stream with all the male employees older than 25.
```

Here is some [reading material](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/) for you! Specially the "2.3 For multiple condition." section.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement certain search functions for each attribute, such as

- for the age the possible filters `'Equal'`, `'Greater than'` or  `'Less than'`
- For the last name the filter `'is equal'`, `'begins with'` or `'ends with'.`
- For the gender `'is male'`

You could add something like below to your Employee class:

```
public static Predicate<Employee> ageEQ(int a) {
    return e -> e.getAge() == a;
}
public static Predicate<Employee> ageGT(int a) {
    return e -> e.getAge() > a;
}
public static Predicate<Employee> ageLT(int a) {
    return e -> e.getAge() < a;
}
public static Predicate<Employee> isMale() {
    return e -> e.getGender().equals("M");
}
public static Predicate<Employee> lastNameEQ(String name) {
    return e -> e.getLastName().equals(name);
}
public static Predicate<Employee> lastNameStartsWith(String name) {
    return e -> e.getLastName().startsWith(name);
}
```

And out a list of Employee:

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Employee(1,22,"M","Aaa","Bar"));
    list.add(new Employee(2,33,"F","Ccc","Ddd"));
    list.add(new Employee(3,44,"M","Eee","Fff"));
    list.add(new Employee(4,55,"F","Ggg","Hhh"));
    list.add(new Employee(5,66,"F","Mmm","Nnn"));
```

to filter for example  all employees who are older than 40 and female:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(Employee.ageGT(40).and(Employee.isMale().negate()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Assuming your request is something like ?age>40&male=false ...

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you need to filter with, you can combine predicates.
Let's say you want to filter Employees with a first name starting with `J`, that are over 37 years old.

```
Predicate<Employee> p = e -> e.getFirstName().startsWith("J");
p = p.and(e -> e.getAge() > 37);
```

You can now use predicate `p` in the filter. You just need to build the final predicate depending on the conditions required.

Comment: Actually that's the point we don't what comes from the request. That's why there is so much possibilities.

Comment: @okduman you mean the users can search however they can think of, giving infinite possibilities? Then you won't be able to handle that with streams. If you have at least some pre-defined search terms, then the amount of predicates is a lot smaller.